Can someone explain Stefan's law for radiation between body and surroundings?
My PE handbook describes how to calculate the "Net Energy Exchange by Radiation Between Two Bodies", as shown below:
"For a body that is small compared to its surroundings:
$\dot Q_{12}=\epsilon \sigma A(T_1^4 - T_2^4)$
Where
$\dot Q_{12}=$ $net$ $heat$ $transfer$ $rate$ $from$ $the$ $body$

$\epsilon=emissivity$ $of$ $the$ $body$

$A=body$ $surface$ $area$

$\sigma =Stefan-Boltzmann$ $constant$

$T_1=absolute$ $temperature$ $of$ $the$ $body$ $surface $

$T_2 =absolute$ $temperature$ $of$ $the$ $surroundings$"

How can a single value of $\epsilon$ be used for heat transfer in both directions? Why does the body need to be small compared to the surroundings?

The Stefan-Boltzmann radiation constant in the ideal model relates a warm object having an ideal black body (a perfect emitter) to that of an ideal cold object, also a black body. The temperature difference determines the radiation rate from the warm to the cold body. An important use is for temperature control calculations for space actuators where the power applied, say, to a motor coil rapidly heats the coil (based upon its thermal mass) but then very slowly cools by means of conduction into its mounting means and ultimately by radiation into space. The surroundings must be large as radiation is in all directions. The value of emissivity is one (1) when everything is ideal. Otherwise is reduced to some fraction of one. Actual conditions are far from ideal and therefore complex.
